# How to close "Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool" tab when running Selenium webdriver (Java)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Currently, when running Selenium chrome webdriver, I always meet "Microsoft Malicious Software Removal Tool" to request if it may reset browser settings. Does anyone can help to prevent it?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run regedit utilliy (in Win 10 you just need to type "regedit" in Cortana and press Enter)
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Google -> Chrome -> *folder with something like "Reset Triggered"
3. Delete whole folder that contains this key. Do not delete other folders, you can break installation

You may need to restart Chrome or even Windows.

For me that's been enough to get rid of this message.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution instead of deleting the folder 'Triggered Reset'
1.Check whether your driver version and chrome browser versions.
For example, if you have a chrome version 88 then need to install a respective driver.
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
2.So, uninstall your existing browser and install a new chrome version 88 and also the new driver from the above link.
this also fixed my existing issue where every time it opens the data tab when executing the selenium script.