# Chrome browser launches default tab titled Settings to reset the setting

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Please i need help with the below:

I am running scripts in my POM project and each time i launch the chrome browser it opens a default tab titled Settings to reset the setting and there is Windows dislogue with heading "Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool - Aug. 2017 wants to reset your settings"

How do i get rid of this as it was not happening before and cant remember doing any changes to my project.
I was using Chrome version 57 and had to upgrade to 61 but there is stilll no change.

```
public void init(String bType) {

        // test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Opening browser- " + bType);
        if (bType.equals("Mozilla"))

            //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", AAConstants.FIREFOX_DRIVER_EXE);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            else if (bType.equals("Chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", AAConstants.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE);

        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Opened browser successfully- " + bType);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the answer to this question, which recommends a regedit to fix the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062090/how-to-close-microsoft-windows-malicious-software-removal-tool-tab-when-runnin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close "Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool" tab when running Selenium webdriver (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062090/how-to-close-microsoft-windows-malicious-software-removal-tool-tab-when-runnin)

Comment: @Rushby, Thank you very much. this is really helpful.